# Fluid image resizing in CSS (or JS?)

Tags: javascript, css, image, fluid-layout

I'm trying to show a fairly large image on a page on my site. I want it to be re-sized dynamically depending on the user's resolution, so that it takes up the same percentage of screen on every monitor. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the percentage values rather than pixels:

```
<img src="path here" width="100%" />
```

Comment: But not both height and width, set only one property and the image will scale.

Answer (score 1):

Set image width to a percentage.