# Automatically Resize Images After Certain Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a webpage with a banner (1024 pixels) and then some pictures in the center region below. I'm looking with CSS (or some other alternative) to start resizing all the images (banner and page icons) downwards automatically if the size of the page in the browser is less than the minimum banner width and if it greater than this minimum size, none of the images are scaled (the banner is on a transparent background so it "resizes fluidly").

This seems like a pretty basic question so I doubt it'll really require all that much but all the other references I saw didn't do it for me (and I am really inept at CSS). Any advice is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Use percentage for width and also media queries for CSS http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fluid image resizing in CSS (or JS?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285302/fluid-image-resizing-in-css-or-js)

Comment: That wouldn't work for me because I only want to scale if the container size is small, not large.

Comment: Why not resize your images/pages in external stylesheets to look how you want it to when your browser resizes? Then in the `html` link to it when the browser is between certain pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries in your CSS - something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #container {
  width:320px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  #container {
  width:700px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 901px) {
  #container {
  width:900px;
  }
}
```

(You can adjust the numbers/brackets).

Then set your image widths as a percentage of the container.

Comment: @sideroxlyon - This seems to be what I'm going for. Now this is where my lack of CSS or HTML experience is coming into play, I don't really know how to choose which container to use or image tag to draw from on the HTML code side of things if I don't know which container they are using in html.

Comment: You can just set the body width (instead of `#container` in the example above) - then find all the images you want to scale and add `style = width:x%` to the `<img>` tag.  YOu can set whatever percentage you want - and different percentage for each image if that helps your page layout.  Without seeing you HTML it's not really possible ot offer much other advice.